# Sliding a table view down and up with a search controller with scope options

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios9, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I cannot seem to get a smooth slide using contentOffset (or a correct position).  I have a search controller and scope bar options below it.

When the search bar is in focus, the scope bar appears but the table view doesn't slide correct. How is this fixed in ios9?

Comment: i don't think it's been fixed at all, unfortunatley, the solution for me was just using a UIViewController then adding a subview tableview and search bar with layout constratints and then animation constraints on touch events with delegation from search bar. Obviously, this isn't ideal for most peopole because you have to use tracking of objects int he table to do the search using predicates yourself.

Comment: So this is an apple bug then?

Comment: I think so, Chris, but the last time I checked was before the last release last week, so maybe it's fixed now, but I'd wait for someone to give you a more thorough answer, if there is one.

Comment: I have tried so many ways of nesting views and playing with offsets

Comment: yeah, so here's how I do it, I set the tableViewHeader view to a UIView with an alpha of 0, then I set the content offset of the UITabeView as animated and this works. This is a super hack, and you will have to add your own gesture recognizers to it, but I have UI under the header view, with custom gestures over the header view to then access the ui below it, this is terribly complex, but this is the solution I use.

Comment: Or, jsut set up the tableview with auto layout, and animate the constraint constant you set up on the NSLayoutAttributeTop, and then animate it however yuo want.